# SQL - find exact match inside a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mySql Data base I have a table with a column for account hierarchy, the values in this column look like this

> /home/first level hierarchy / second level hierarchy / third level hierarchy/

(some have only one level and some have 3 levels)

I want to get only the first level hierarchy items

my SQL query looks like this

```
SELECT Account.name FROM Account WHERE account_hierarchy like "/home/%/"
```

the problem is that i am getting in the result all the levels after home since they all ends with /

is there any way in SQL to get only the first level

Comment: how do you identify 1st, 2nd , 3rd level?? by /  ?

Comment: `select regexp_substr('/a/b/c','[a-z]+',3);` returns `b`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: Won't all rows have at least the first level?  Are you saying a row could have a home but no first level?

Comment: @Gary_W each row can have a variation of names for example one is just /home/ another can be /home/first level hierarchy/ and another can be /home/first level hierarchy/second level hierarchy/. all are starting with /home/

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am using MySQL database i added it to the tag

Comment: @NoChance I am using MySQL database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want exactly three slashes.  You can get that using:

```
where hierarchy like '/home/%/' and
      hierarchy not like '/home/%/%/'
```

In databases that support regular expressions, there are alternative solutions.

Actually, if you want just a beginning and ending slash, then there is no slash in the middle with other characters around it.  So you can use:

```
where hierarchy not like '/home/%_/_%'
```

This assumes that all begin with `'/home/'`.

Comment: this approach solved my problem thank you !
i used "Account.hierarchy' not like '/home/%/%/' AND
Account.hierarchy<>'/home/'
and got only the first level hierarchy results

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr)

Example:

`SELECT regexp_substr('/a/b/c','[a-z]+',3)`, returns `b`

Because 'b' is the piece after the second '/'.

You might need to change the regular expression `'[a-z]+'`. This on only matches lower-case paths. If you also need upper-case matches, change it to `[a-zA-Z]+`.

All the other posibilitues of regular expressions (in MySQL) are explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

Comment: I tried the REGEXP approach but got errors (maybe it due to the fact that i didn't implement it correctly)